# Material-UI and gatsby official example

Tags: material-ui

I am using gatsby and material UI according to the official example and I am wondering if I have to add the `withRoot` wrapper to EVERY component that uses MUI or if I can just wrap the highest level component that I want to use MUI?

I am having trouble with the render and IDK how to track down the cause. In dev everything works great, but in prod, `<Grid>` alignments are off and on the initial render, there are no styles applied. They are applied a second or two after the first paint.

I have followed the example exactly and wrapped only my global layout component.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the sames issues when starting to work with [gatsby 2 (latest beta)](https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/) and [MaterialUI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui).

[After some research](https://github.com/natterstefan/react-trello-multiboard-page/pull/1#issue-198749718) I stumbled upon very helpful comments on GitHub. [I summarized my learnings](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5667#issuecomment-403191861) (with the links to the mentioned comments and solutions) in one of the issues on GitHub. You can find them [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5667#issuecomment-403191861).

I hope this helps you and others.