# Gatsby with Material-UI: Why createPageContext?

Tags: javascript, node.js, material-ui, gatsby

I was going through the gatsby example on the [material-ui project](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/gatsby) page on github and hoping for an explanation of a few codelines.

In the file [getPageContext.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/examples/gatsby/src/getPageContext.js#L40)

```
export default function getPageContext() {
  // Make sure to create a new context for every server-side request so that data
  // isn't shared between connections (which would be bad).
  if (!process.browser) {
    return createPageContext();
}
```

**Why would data be shared between connections?**

I would expect a warning about this behavior somewhere in the Material-UI documentation but it is nowhere to be found. This seems so important that I wonder why it is buried in a code example.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376660/material-ui-and-gatsby-official-example) seems to be related however the linked github issue + discussion do not help me understand why there is this workaround with the page context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PageContext as illustrated in the example is implemented to have a proper CSS injection order as outlined [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#css-injection-order):

> The CSS injected by Material-UI to style a component has the highest
>   specificity possible as the  is injected at the bottom of the
>    to ensure the components always render correctly.

The important bit is in [withRoot.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/examples/gatsby/src/withRoot.js#L23):

```
  return (
    <JssProvider generateClassName={this.muiPageContext.generateClassName}>
      {/* MuiThemeProvider makes the theme available down the React
          tree thanks to React context. */}
      <MuiThemeProvider
        theme={this.muiPageContext.theme}
        sheetsManager={this.muiPageContext.sheetsManager}
      >
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...this.props} />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </JssProvider>
    );
```

This [thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5667) gives insight into what happens if you don't work with a pageContext.